# Sending data using POST from PHP to raspberry's Python script

Tags: php, python-3.x, server, httprequest, raspberry-pi3

i recently found the way to send data from a python file to a php file using request post and now i would like to be able to send data always with the same method of a php file to a python file knowing that my file php is in a server and the python file is in a raspberry that is connected to the 3g Internet, but I do not know too much about this domain i am still new i show you my code to send a python file to a PHP file :

raspberry python client :

```
import requests
import time
i =1
j= 0
while i==1 :
   j = j+1
   userdata = {"id": j ,  "firstname": "jo", "lastname": "rasp",
               "password": "666"}
   resp = requests.post('http://jawad.meswatts.fr/sous/api.php',
                          data = userdata)
   print(resp.text)
   time.sleep(3)
```

php server script :

```
<?php
try
    {
      $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jawad;charset=utf8',
                     'jawad', 'knlnklml54vn,6');
    }
   catch(Exception $e)
   {
     die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
   }


      $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST["id"]);
      $firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]);
      $lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["lastname"]);
      $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);


      $req = $bdd->prepare( '                            
                            INSERT INTO reception(nom,prenom,identifiant,id)
                            VALUES (:lastname,:firstname,:password,:id);
                            ' );

    $req->execute(array('lastname' => $lastname, 'firstname' => 
                       $firstname,'password' => $password,'id' => $id)); 
  ?>
```

So here are my two programs that work very well now I would like to do that in the other way I know PHP very well but I'm not very very strong network can you help me please ?

Comment: Basically you have to invert the papers, is that correct?

Comment: yes exactly ! knowing that the Raspberry is connected in 3G it has an IP address that I can store on my database and use it thereafter

Comment: In that case you have to find a way to build a web server using python and run it on pi. It should be possible by using some library already available.

Comment: I already tried some examples by simulating a python server but I did not arrive because I do not master very well would you have a concrete example to give me for my problematic ?

Comment: There's this python server with several methods already implemented. All you have to do is to connect the dots and save data to a database. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/2219997. In terms of php, you would simply need to translate the python code to php.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with your current plan is that you must be able to POST *to* somewhere.

In the case of the pi posting to the server, we are posting *to* `http://jawad.meswatts.fr/sous/api.php`

But if the server wanted to post to the pi. Where would it post to? The pi isn't publicly available at any domain name or public IP. (Its possible to set it up this way, but I wouldn't recommend it for beginners).

Instead I would start with how everyone else has solved this in the past. Have the pi make a GET request to another location on the server. This function would return the information that would have been posted. In this way, the server never tries to find the pi. It just waits until it is told to store some information (POST) or until it is asked what some information is (GET).

Comment: thank you for your answer unfortunately it is not suitable for what I want to do in my project indeed I do not want to send a message directly back but it is a message that can be sent at any time knowing that the Raspberry is connected in 3G it has an IP address that I can store on my database and that I can use thereafter to make the request is more secure but I would like to know what is the way to do that!

Comment: You can use polling to always get (semi) up to date information from the server. (i.e. make a GET request, then a few minutes later make anothe, then another, etc). If you _truly_ need full duplex, fully async communication between the pi and the server. You could use POSTs back and forth. The pi will need to have server software installed to handle the POSTs. I still wouldn't recommend that. You could use a websocket connection. That gives you full duplex, fully async communication, without having to mess around with storing the pi's IP or setting up a server on the pi.

Comment: thank you for the clarification you add however there are other details to consider in my project I can not send every minute a data get because I have to monitor the consumption of Internet and electricity !

Comment: in the documentation I read a lot of articles on the full-duplex WebSocket and I tried some examples but I did not do too well and as for the storage of IP addresses even if I do not pass not by the method POST the IP addresses will be stored later in my database as the future goal and to have several raspberry connect to the server and to manage each and to communicate with them must their IP address mandatory so i can use IP address right now !! but now that I think maybe a 3G connection does not give me a public ip address another problematic arghhhhhhhh

Comment: You could ask a question about websockets! specifically 1. how to set up a websocket server in php, 2. how to set up a websocket client in python. As for storing the IPs, I wouldn't recommend you use those as a way to identify which pi you are talking to. The ISP can assign IPs in anyway they choose, there's no reason they can't remove an IP from one pi and assign it to another. For device identification you could use the MAC address, those are unique per device and never change. Or set up some other registration system that the pi's use and store a unique value to communicate with the server.

Comment: thanks you  Kallmanation !! I think I will ask a new question in the forum about WebSocket to have a PHP server side and a client side websocket python raspberry taking into account that the raspberry and connect in 3G